# output parameter returns null value when I run on ADO. NET in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I'm sure this question has already been answered in this forum. I went through most of them and tried all the possible fixes but it did not work in my case. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

My stored procedure works fine in SQL Server Management Studio. It is returning the output whenever I run my stored procedure. But the output parameter returns **NULL** value when I call it from my ADO. NET code. I'm pretty new to this. Any help to resolve this issue is very much appreciated.

Stored Procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ZebraGetEmpName]
@EmpId int,
@EmpName varchar(40) out
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT EmployeeName
    FROM  ZebraPrinter.dbo.EmployeeInfo
    WHERE EmpID = @EmpId

    RETURN (@EmpName)
END

GO
```

ADO .NET Code :

```
public string GetEmpName(int EmpId)
    {
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ZebraPrinterConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_ZebraGetEmpName", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpId",EmpId);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmpName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40);
            cmd.Parameters["@EmpName"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;                

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            con.Close();

            string EmpName = cmd.Parameters["@EmpName"].Value.ToString();


            return (EmpName);


    }
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: The **RETURN** value from a stored procedure can only ever be an integer type (typically used as an "error" code, or a number of rows affected info) - you **cannot** send back a string using `RETURN`. Instead, you need to *assign it* to the output parameter you have in place

Comment: And when wanting to use an output parameter (which there can be multiple) you don't put it in a return. You set the value and retrieve the value from the calling code.

Comment: See [the MSDN docs on stored procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188655.aspx) - it says: *A procedure can return an **integer** value called a return code to indicate the execution status of a procedure.*

Answer (score 2):

You didn't assign any values to `@EmpName` variable in procedure so it will be `NULL`. Change the select query to assign value to `@EmpName`

Also you don't need procedure to do this.

```
SELECT @EmpName=EmployeeName
FROM  ZebraPrinter.dbo.EmployeeInfo
WHERE EmpID = @EmpId
```

Comment: You *cannot* return a `VARCHAR(40)` variable using the `RETURN` statement. Only `INT` values (error codes, rows affected) can be `RETURN`ed from a SQL Server stored procedure .....

Comment: @marc_s - Yeah agreed. It is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

You getting the null value in the output parameter because you are not assigning the value to the output parameter.

When you are using a output parameter then you have to set it's value in the stored procedure to use it's value later.

Use:

```
SET @EmpName = (SELECT TOP 1 EmployeeName
                FROM ZebraPrinter.dbo.EmployeeInfo
                WHERE EmpID = @EmpId)
```

and your stored procedure should be like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ZebraGetEmpName]
    @EmpId int,
    @EmpName varchar(40) out
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @EmpName = (SELECT TOP 1 EmployeeName
                    FROM ZebraPrinter.dbo.EmployeeInfo
                    WHERE EmpID = @EmpId)

END

GO
```

Comment: Your code would work without using top even if it found more than 1 row. The value would be from the last row (with no order by you just don't know which one it would be).

Comment: i think no, 
it would give me..
`Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`@SeanLange

Comment: True enough. I never set variables like that using a subquery. I would use "Select @EmpName = EmployeeName etc...". You can set multiple values and you don't have the issue with subqueries and multiple rows.

Comment: Thank you so much @user3540365. It worked :).. It was just a small stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Returning something, setting an output parameter value, and selecting something are three different things.

You can set @EmpName like NoDisplayName's answer and leave your C# code as-is, or you can just run the select and pull the value when you execute the query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ZebraGetEmpName]
@EmpId int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT EmployeeName
    FROM  ZebraPrinter.dbo.EmployeeInfo
    WHERE EmpID = @EmpId
END

string empName = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

What you're seeing in Management Studio when you run this is not the return value, but rather the query result. The return value of your query would be null.